# Animation only runs two times, then stops working?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have a `RelativeLayout` that displays some controls, and I want to hide and show them using a slide up/down animation.

This is working fine for the first slide down and the following slide up, but after that it stops working for no apparent reason.

Here's the code for performing the animations:

```
    final ViewGroup controlsLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.controlsLayout);
    final boolean show = controlsLayout.getTag() instanceof Boolean && controlsLayout.getTag().equals(Boolean.FALSE);

    Animation anim;
    if( show ) {
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
        controlsLayout.setTag(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    else{
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
        controlsLayout.setTag(Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // If we slided down, then hide the controls after the slide is done
            if( !show )
                controlsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    // Before starting the animation, we make sure the view is visible
    controlsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    controlsLayout.startAnimation(anim);
```

The value of the variable `show` toggles as expected on each run. The first time the code is run, the controls slide down. The next time they slide up. But the next time (even though show is toggled), the animation doesn't even start...

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

**slide_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you set your layout to `controlsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);` android is not rendering your layout on next run and here you are attempting to animate on a view that has not been rendered yet, the animation will occur on the view without a layout. After the animation has completed, it will render it and suddenly the view will appear without animation.

So I would suggest u to keep the visibility to INVISIBLE instead of GONE, and if you can't do that then you should make it invisible first then apply animation and then after animation make it visible.

one other way could be to simply use `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in your `xml` for default animation and its pretty good.

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately I tried both those options already. `INVISIBLE` gives the same result as `GONE`, i.e. nothing happens on the third animation (the view stays in place - it neither animates nor disappears). As you can see I set the view to `VISIBLE` before starting the animation. Using `animateLayoutChanges="true"` works fine, but I want a sliding animation, not a fading one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well this was stupid. Now the exact same code I posted in my question works. The problem seems to have been the "Instant Run" feature in Android Studio 2.0. For some reason the code didn't work when it was "uploaded" to my phone using "Instant Run", but when I did a total restart and rebuild of the app it works.

Anyway, here is an alternative solution I found while trying to find a working solution, using `ObjectAnimator`.

```
    final ViewGroup controlsLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.controlsLayout);

    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
            controlsLayout,
            "translationY",
            controlsLayout.getTranslationY(),
            (controlsLayout.getTranslationY() > 0) ? 0 : controlsLayout.getHeight()
    ).start();
```